# Calculate SUM total of several derived columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know if there is a way to find summation of already calculated derived columns into a new column.

```
Employee_KT_State
--------------------------------------------------------
Emp_Id      Team           KT_State            Left_Org
----------------------------------------------------------
 101        Orange         In Progress          2016
 102        Red            Complete             2016
 103        Orange         Complete             N
 104        Green          In Progress          N
 105        Orange         Not Started          N
 106        Green          Not Started          2015
 107        Red            In Progress          N
 108        Red            Complete             N
 109        Green          Complete             N
-----------------------------------------------------------

SELECT
  SUM(if (KT_State = 'In Progress' AND Team = 'Red', 1, 0)) AS 'Red In Progress Count',
  SUM(if (KT_State = 'In Progress' AND Team = 'Green', 1, 0)) AS 'Green In Progress Count',
  SUM(if (KT_State = 'In Progress' AND Team = 'Orange', 1, 0)) AS 'Orange In Progress Count'
   SUM(if (KT_State = 'Complete' AND Team = 'Green', 1, 0)) AS 'Green Complete Count'
    FROM 
       Employee_KT_State
```

I'm trying to add Green In progress and Complete Count. Instead of having another SUM with different if conditions, can I directly use the count derived from the 2nd and the 4th column?

```
 something like - 

  SELECT
   SUM(if (KT_State = 'In Progress' AND Team = 'Red', 1, 0)) AS 'Red In Progress Count',
   SUM(if (KT_State = 'In Progress' AND Team = 'Green', 1, 0)) AS 'Green In Progress Count',
   SUM(if (KT_State = 'In Progress' AND Team = 'Orange', 1, 0)) AS 'Orange In Progress Count'
   SUM(if (KT_State = 'Complete' AND Team = 'Green', 1, 0)) AS 'Green Complete Count',
   'Green In Progress Count' + 'Green Complete Count' AS ' Green In-Progress and Complete Count'   --> Will this yield me results??
    FROM 
       Employee_KT_State
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No, you cannot use a column alias in the `select` where it is defined.

Comment: Ok, so do you recommend me using the 1st query as subquery and the actual query to calculate the summation of individual columns ?

Comment: Either way's fine

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can simplify code to:

```
SELECT SUM(KT_State = 'In Progress' AND Team = 'Red') AS `Red In Progress Count`,
       SUM(KT_State = 'In Progress' AND Team = 'Green') AS `Green In Progress Count`,
       SUM(KT_State = 'In Progress' AND Team = 'Orange') AS `Orange In Progress Count`,
       SUM(KT_State = 'Complete' AND Team = 'Green') AS `Green Complete Count`,
FROM Employee_KT_State;
```

To get your two additional columns, you need to explicitly have the `SUM()` expression.

Note that I changed the column names to use backticks for the column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: Thanks for the response Gordon. Unfortunately, I need the count of Green In Progress as well as Green Complete as stated in the question.

Comment: @SrinivasLakshman . . . You seem to know how to do that calculation.  You can't use a short-cut.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery

```
SELECT t.*,
       `Green In Progress Count` + `Green Complete Count` 
          As ` Green In-Progress and Complete Count`
FROM (
  SELECT
    SUM(if (KT_State = 'In Progress' AND Team = 'Red', 1, 0)) AS `Red In Progress Count`,
    SUM(if (KT_State = 'In Progress' AND Team = 'Green', 1, 0)) AS `'Green In Progress Count`,
    SUM(if (KT_State = 'In Progress' AND Team = 'Orange', 1, 0)) AS `Orange In Progress Count`
    SUM(if (KT_State = 'Complete' AND Team = 'Green', 1, 0)) AS `Green Complete Count`
  FROM 
         Employee_KT_State
) t
```

---

Simplified demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7ddd8c/2

```
SELECT t.*,
       `Green In Progress Count` + `Green Complete Count` 
          As ` Green In-Progress and Complete Count`
FROM (
     SELECT x As `Green In Progress Count`,
            2* x As `Green Complete Count`
     FROM Employee_KT_State
) t

| Green In Progress Count | Green Complete Count | Green In-Progress and Complete Count |
|-------------------------|----------------------|--------------------------------------|
|                       1 |                    2 |                                    3 |
|                       2 |                    4 |                                    6 |
|                       3 |                    6 |                                    9 |
```

Comment: Thank you ! I shall be doing the same !